# Seeking Resources on Hermeneutical Interpretation of Scripture Influenced by Egyptian Culture

Tags: cultural-analysis, egypt, historical-criticism, resource-request

I recently heard an interesting perspective from an Adventist Christian pastor and archaeologist regarding the potential influence of Egyptian culture on biblical scriptures. Specifically, he pointed out the notion that God's refusal to reveal His true name to Moses in the scriptures might be linked to an Egyptian tradition. In this tradition, knowing the true name of an entity, including deities, was believed to grant control over it. This concept is reflected in the Egyptian practice of having two names: one public and one secret.

Given Moses' upbringing and immersion in Egyptian culture, it's plausible that these cultural norms could have subconsciously influenced his writing or transcribing of the scriptures. In light of this, I am searching for scholarly resources, such as books or systematic studies, that offer a hermeneutical interpretation of the scriptures, particularly focusing on the influence of Egyptian culture and traditions. Can anyone recommend comprehensive works that explore this specific aspect of biblical hermeneutics?

Comment: Would your request not be outside the scope of 'Biblical' hermeneutics, seeking, instead, Egyptian hermeneutics?

Comment: God did not 'refuse to reveal his true name' to Moses. God stated exactly whom he was and exactly what he was. 'I am that I am'. The name later revealed is 'Father' whom only the coming, in person, of the Son could reveal. Egyptian tradition is irrelevant.

Comment: Search for the latest books on higher criticism on OT. Though it maybe somewhat outdated as it was perhaps biased and ignored the literary nature. Start reading books on narrative criticism for better understanding the Bible. These are possibilities, it's hard that anyone here would know it. There shouldn't be any surprise for such similarities.

Comment: Anne, no it is a biblical hermeneutics topic only asking on the background or source of text. See Formal Criticism and higher criticism.

Comment: The question is appropriate under the heading of "hermeneutical approaches" which is defined in  the tag-description as including  *historical/cultural analysis* and  *contextual analysis*... I have taken the liberty of including the tag in the OP.

Comment: @DanFefferman No, this question isn't *about* any hermeneutical approach (merely using a hermeneutical approach does not warrant using that tag, or else it would have to be applied to almost every question!) It's just a context question. But I think it's too broad. We could perhaps edit the hermeneutical-approaches tag description.

Comment: I would not mind seeing it moved to Christianity.se.... but that site is for Christians, while this one welcomes Jewish perspectives... and secular ones. My main concern that a question like this deserve an answer somewhere.

Comment: but I also insist that "historical/cultural analysis" (a topic under the hermeneutical approaches tag) is specifically what this question asks for. I admit that it doesn't start with a biblical text but that requirement is specifically waved in this case. The help page says "Questions that do not arise from a Biblical text are off-topic unless they are about hermeneutical approaches."

Comment: Historical criticism is another tag that fits this question... I discuss how this approach deals with Egyptian influence on the biblical text in my answer.

Comment: @Anne, ou make a valid point about the scope of hermeneutics. The request, however, isn't for Egyptian hermeneutics per se, but rather for an exploration of how Egyptian cultural influences might be reflected in biblical texts. This approach still falls within the realm of biblical hermeneutics, as it seeks to deepen our understanding of the scriptures by considering the potential impact of Moses' Egyptian upbringing on his writings.

Comment: @NigelJ, you're right that in Exodus, God reveals Himself to Moses as "I am that I am," signifying His eternal nature. The mention of Egyptian influence is not to dispute this, but to explore how Moses' Egyptian background might have shaped his presentation of these revelations. This approach doesn't challenge the theological content but seeks to understand the scriptures within a wider historical and cultural context. It's a common method in biblical scholarship to enrich our understanding of the text.

Comment: @Michael16, Thank you for the suggestions. Exploring both higher criticism of the Old Testament and narrative criticism could indeed offer valuable insights into understanding the Bible. Appreciate the guidance on these methodologies, and I'll certainly look into the latest resources in these areas for a more nuanced perspective.

Comment: Thanks, Humberto, I already found a book ref while searching google advance book search. Karl Luckert, Monotheism of Moses. That is what maybe the particular book, quite informative. I voted to reopen the question. If it doesn't open soon, like till tomorrow, u should make a topic regarding this on the meta site. This question is not just on topic, but it is on the primarily hermeneutical acc to site rules. Ques like this are informative and helpful for all.

Comment: Humberto, dont worry about editing the question, it is perfectly fine. The issue is the misunderstanding and misguided culture of this site that closes these topics. The question language does not have to change to suit others expectations. It is on topic question.

Comment: I found its ref on Egyptian Light and Hebrew Fire
Theological and Philosophical Roots of Christendom in Evolutionary Perspective
By Karl W. Luckert · 1991 , chapter Monotheism of Moses, p. 125. It seems the mods will not open the ques since the secular scholarship go against their religious tenets and dogma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP mentions the Egyptian tradition of power in knowing a deity's true name. Some commentators see an echo of this in the interaction between Moses and Yahweh in Exodus. Here, God reveals his true name, YHWH, usually rendered as "the LORD" in English, reflecting the idea that God's name is so holy that it must not be pronounced.

Exodus 3

> 13 Then Moses said to God, “If I come to the people of Israel and say
> to them, ‘The God of your fathers has sent me to you,’ and they ask
> me, ‘What is his name?’ what shall I say to them?” 14 God said to
> Moses, “I am who I am.” And he said, “Say this to the people of
> Israel, ‘I am has sent me to you.’” 15 God also said to Moses, “Say
> this to the people of Israel, ‘The Lord, the God of your fathers,
> the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, has sent
> me to you’: this is my name for ever, and thus I am to be remembered
> throughout all generations.

Regarding books on the subject, Joseph Campbell deals with Egyptian influence on the Bible his book [Oriental Mythology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1608687287). For example, he shows that the Egyptian Serpent archetype was associated with healing and eternal life. Campbell and others see the Bible's story of the Bronze Serpent made by Moses as preserving this Egyptian tradition.

Numbers 21

> the Lord said to Moses, “Make a fiery serpent, and set it on a pole;
> and every one who is bitten, when he sees it, shall live.” 9 So Moses
> made a bronze serpent, and set it on a pole; and if a serpent bit any
> man, he would look at the bronze serpent and live.

During the time of King Hezekiah, this artifact was destroyed on the grounds that it was the object of idolatrous worship (2 Kings 18:4).

Campbell, together with various authors of the historical-critical school, also see the story of Eve and the serpent in Gen. 3 as a sort of turning the Egyptian and Babylonian myths on their head: instead of the Egyptian goddess Isis bringing life to people with the aid of the eternally self-begetting serpent, the female figure becomes the originator of sin while the serpent, instead of being a symbol of eternal life and healing, becomes an agent of death.

[image]

Regarding the New Testament some writers see Egyptian iconography of Isis and Horus behind Christian icons of Mary and Jesus. Others see a parallel between icons associated with the [Four Evangelists](https://aleteia.org/2019/08/20/ox-eagle-lion-man-why-and-how-are-the-evangelists-associated-with-these-creatures/) and Egyptian counterparts. Parallels to the story of Cain and Abel and other biblical events have also been mentioned.

Additional resources:

- [Isis Mary Sophia: Her Mission and Ours](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0880104945)
- [Egyptian Mythology and Egyptian Christianity illustrated](https://www.amazon.com/Egyptian-Mythology-Christianity-illustrated/)
- An article by Alice Grenfell entitled [Egyptian Mythology on the Bible](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/27899648.pdf) gives additional examples.
- Freud famously addressed this subject in his book [Moses and Monotheism](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0394700147) although. His idea that Judaism inherited monotheism from the Egyptian king Akhenaten has been a fertile one, although the Freudian context of the this hypothesis has lost influence almost entirely.

Comment: about the name question, i register this passage: Revelation 2:17: o the one who is victorious, I will give some of the hidden manna. I will also give that person a white stone with a new name written on it, known only to the one who receives it.